# TypeScript - Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I am facing this error when I try to `map` over the array based on dynamic key from a union prop type.

This is the error

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

This is the structure

```
type Props = {
  folder: ABC
}

type Tag = {
  id: string
  title: string
  type: CommonProps
}

type CommonProps = {
  type: 'green' | 'red' | 'blue'
}

type A = {
  is_ready: boolean
  green_tags: Array<Tag>
} & CommonProps

type B = {
  address: string
  blue_tags: Array<Tag>
} & CommonProps

type C = {
  description: string
  red_tags: Array<Tag>
} & CommonProps

type ABC = A | B | C

const App = ({ folder }: Props) => {
...

  const getTagsArrayBasedOnItemType = () => {
    const tagsArrayName = `${folder.type}_tags`

    return !isEmpty(folder[tagsArrayName as keyof ABC])
      ? folder[tagsArrayName as keyof ABC].map((e: any) => e.title)
      : []
  }
```

If I remove `as keyof ABC` then I see the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'A | B | C'.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

My primitive solution (not ideal at all)

```
type CommonTagsArray = {
  green_tags: Array<Tag>
  blue_tags: Array<Tag>
  red_tags: Array<Tag>
}

type A = {
  is_ready: boolean
} & CommonProps & CommonTagsArray

type B = {
  address: string
} & CommonProps & CommonTagsArray

type C = {
  description: string
} & CommonProps & CommonTagsArray


  const getTagsArrayBasedOnItemType = () => {
    switch (folder.type) {
      case 'green':
        return folder.green_tags.map(
          (tag: Tag) => tag.title,
        )
      case 'blue':
        return folder.blue_tags.map(
          (tag: Tag) => tag.title,
        )
      case 'red':
        return folder.red_tags.map(
          (tag: Tag) => tag.title,
        )
      default:
        return []
    }
  }
```